# wix upgrade shouldn't remove files installed by other components in the installer

Tags: wix, installation, upgrade

I have a wix bootstrapper application which installs various components on the system. Now I have made changes to the installer in such a way that the files that were installed by the last component in my older installer is now being installed by the first component in my newer installer. This gets me to the upgrade problem. When I upgrade, the files that the newer installer should copy aren't getting copied since the older install already installed these files. But when the newer installer comes to the last component, that component is being removed since this is an upgrade which removes the files as well and since in the newer install the last component doesn't copy those files, I end with those files missing in the upgrade process. How can this be resolved? Thanks for the help in advance. Let me know if I should make the question more clear.

EDIT: To explain with an example

Older Installer

```
Application
    Module 1
    Module 2
    Module 3
        Copies files 1,2,3
```

Newer Installer

```
Application
    Module 1
        Copies files 1,2,3
    Module 2
    Module 3
```

Now in the upgrade scenario, when the Older Installer is already installed the files1,2,3 are already present on the system. Now when I try to install the Newer Installer, then at the time of installing Module 1, it sees that the files 1,2,3 are already present. Then when it reaches installation of Module 3, it first removes the existing Module 3 (Older Installer) which in turn removes the files 1,2,3. The Module 3 of the Newer installer doesn't copy those files, since in the newer installer it is the job of Module 1. Because of this I end up losing files 1,2,3 as part of the upgrade.

Comment: Can you post the xml contents or at least a snippet? You may just need to reorder things.

Comment: @RobinJohnson Thanks for the comment Robin but the files that I want to copy are basically a ComponentGroupRef to a heat generated wxs file which has all the information of the files to be copied. Anyways, I solved my problem by duplicating the reference to the ComponentGroup in all the modules. What this does is that when the Module 3 of the old installer is being uninstalled it removes those files and when the Module 3 of the new installer is being installed it adds those files back again since it has the reference to the ComponentGroup.

Comment: Good. Perfectly reasonable solution.